# Scipy error: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility (and associated strange behavior)

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am installing numpy/scipy/scikit-learn on OS X 10.9.4, and am getting errors about "numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility".

Here's what I did to construct the repo:

```
mkvirtualenv thm
workon thm
pip install numpy scipy pandas ipython # and some other stuff
cd /path/to/our/repo
# run tests
```

Here's a traceback excerpt of a relevant warning (turned into an error because we use `warnings.simplefilter('error')` at the beginning of our tests):

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: RuntimeWarning (numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary in
compatibility)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py",
 line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py
", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py
", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/ben/code/thm/alpha/prosper/base/stats/test_auc.py", line 3, in <m
odule>
    import sklearn.metrics
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/
__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .metrics import (accuracy_score,
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 27, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming as sp_hamming
  File "/Users/ben/.virtualenvs/thm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .ckdtree import *
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init scipy.spatial.ckdtree (scipy/spatial/ckdtree.c:20570)
RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
```

I'm told that this warning is caused by scipy being compiled against a different version of numpy than the one installed. However, I installed them all with pip in what I thought was a pretty standard way, so this shouldn't be a problem, I would think.

Weirdly, although running our entire test suite as a whole (via `python -m unittest discover`) gives these errors, running the individual tests (via `python -m unittest <module>`) works fine.

According to the tests, here's some relevant version info:

```
numpy version 1.9.0 (rev 07601a64cdfeb1c0247bde1294ad6380413cab66)
scipy version 0.14.0 (built against numpy 1.9.0)
sklearn version 0.15.2
pandas version 0.14.1
```

Happy to provide more info on request!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How did you build sklearn 0.14.1? Did you build it against the same version of numpy as you did for scipy?

Recent versions of scikit-learn, scipy and numpy have prebuilt-packages. In particular scikit-learn 0.15.2 should be binary compatible with numpy 1.7+. I think the same is true with scipy 0.14.0 but you said you built it yourself from source, which is not what pip should do by default (it should just install the prebuilt whl package).

*Edit*: have you tried to do:

```
pip install -U scipy scikit-learn pandas
```

to make sure that you are using the latest stable versions of the whl for those packages?

*Edit*: The comment below has the actual answer that works and is presumably why this answer was accepted.  Namely:

```
pip uninstall -y scipy scikit-learn
pip install --no-binary scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry--that version of sklearn was from a previous version of the post where I was using our customized version of scikit-learn. I then switched to stock sklearn and updated the post (since I was still seeing the problem), but forgot to update that line. I've edited the post to match. My scipy, scikit-learn and pandas are now all at the latest version and the command you suggested does nothing.

Comment: Also, I didn't build scipy from source. In fact, perhaps that's the problem? You mentioned prebuilt packages--is there a way to tell Pip *not* to use prebuilt packages and to build the stuff myself? From the output, it looks like Pip compiled numpy itself, but not scipy.

Comment: This is weird, I am running exactly the same setup and I cannot reproduce the problem you report. numpy 1.9.0 should be ABI compatible with previous versions.

Anyway you can use: `pip uninstall -y scipy scikit-learn && pip install  –no-use-wheel scipy scikit-learn` to re-build scikit-learn and scipy from source instead of using the wheels, but they should work with new version of numpy.

Comment: ogrisel, is numpy 1.9 compatible with 1.6.2? My system numpy is v1.6.2, so maybe it's getting linked in somewhere it shouldn't?

Comment: I just built `scipy==0.14.0` against `numpy==1.9.0` while still using the whl package for `scikit-learn==0.15.2` and I can run `python -c "from sklearn.metrics import *"` without any warning.

Comment: "My system numpy is v1.6.2, so maybe it's getting linked in somewhere it shouldn't?": this is weird, scipy and scikit-learn should build against the numpy installed in your active python `site-packages`, not any system lib from another python interpreter.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what was going on, but removing numpy, scipy, scikit-learn and pandas and rebuilding them all via `pip install --no-use-wheel` worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's bad though. I wish I could find a way to reproduce your problem to have whl package that are binary compatible by default.

Comment: FYI, `--no-use-wheel` is deprecated and will be removed in the future.  Please use `--no-binary` instead.