# RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have this error for trying to load a saved SVM model. I have tried uninstalling sklearn, NumPy and SciPy, reinstalling the latest versions all-together again (using pip). I am still getting this error. Why?

```
In [1]: import sklearn; print sklearn.__version__
0.18.1
In [3]: import numpy; print numpy.__version__
1.11.2
In [5]: import scipy; print scipy.__version__
0.18.1
In [7]: import pandas; print pandas.__version__
0.19.1

In [10]: clf = joblib.load('model/trained_model.pkl')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeWarning                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5e5db1331757> in <module>()
----> 1 clf = joblib.load('sentiment_classification/model/trained_model.pkl')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.pyc in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    573                     return load_compatibility(fobj)
    574
--> 575                 obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    576
    577     return obj

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.pyc in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    505     obj = None
    506     try:
--> 507         obj = unpickler.load()
    508         if unpickler.compat_mode:
    509             warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "

/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    862             while 1:
    863                 key = read(1)
--> 864                 dispatch[key](self)
    865         except _Stop, stopinst:
    866             return stopinst.value

/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load_global(self)
   1094         module = self.readline()[:-1]
   1095         name = self.readline()[:-1]
-> 1096         klass = self.find_class(module, name)
   1097         self.append(klass)
   1098     dispatch[GLOBAL] = load_global

/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in find_class(self, module, name)
   1128     def find_class(self, module, name):
   1129         # Subclasses may override this
-> 1130         __import__(module)
   1131         mod = sys.modules[module]
   1132         klass = getattr(mod, name)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 # License: BSD 3 clause (C) INRIA 2010
     12
---> 13 from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
     14         LinearSVR
     15 from .bounds import l1_min_c

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3
----> 4 from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
      5 from ..base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
      6 from ..linear_model.base import LinearClassifierMixin, SparseCoefMixin, \

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in <module>()
      6 from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
      7
----> 8 from . import libsvm, liblinear
      9 from . import libsvm_sparse
     10 from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin

__init__.pxd in init sklearn.svm.libsvm (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:10207)()

RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 80
```

**UPDATE:** OK, by following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752444/scipy-error-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-and), and

```
pip uninstall -y scipy scikit-learn
pip install --no-binary scipy scikit-learn
```

The error has now gone, though I still have no idea why it occurred in the first place...

Comment: `--no-use-wheel` recompiles the module from source against whatever you have on your system.

Comment: In newer versions of pip this command has been renamed to `--no-binary`.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me: `pip install --no-binary :all: pandas` . FWIW I was getting this error on a fresh VE build on top of Python version `Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.` with only `requests` and `pandas` installed in the environment.

Comment: Should be fixed now in cython 0.29, as commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040459/2802665)

Comment: You also need to install `gfortran` for scipy to compile: `sudo apt install gfortran`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

According to [MAINT: silence Cython warnings about changes dtype/ufunc size. - numpy/numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/432):

> These warnings are visible whenever you import scipy (or another
>   package) that was compiled against an older numpy than is installed.

and the checks are inserted by Cython (hence are present in any module compiled with it).

Long story short, **these warnings should be benign in the particular case of `numpy`**, and **these messages are filtered out since `numpy 1.8`** (the branch this commit went onto). While [`scikit-learn 0.18.1` is compiled against `numpy 1.6.1`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

**To filter these warnings yourself**, you can do the same [as the patch does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/432/commits/170ed4e33d6196d724dc18ddcd42311c291b4587?diff=split):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.dtype size changed")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.ufunc size changed")
```

Of course, **you can just recompile all affected modules from source against your local `numpy`** with `pip install --no-binary :all:`¹ **instead** if you have the <s>balls</s> tools for that.

---

Longer story: the patch's proponent [claims](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/432#issuecomment-8401294) there should be no risk specifically with `numpy`, and 3rd-party packages are intentionally built against older versions:

> [Rebuilding everything against current numpy is] not a feasible
>   solution, and certainly shouldn't be necessary. Scipy (as many other
>   packages) is compatible with a number of versions of numpy. So when we
>   distribute scipy binaries, we build them against the lowest supported
>   numpy version (1.5.1 as of now) and they work with 1.6.x, 1.7.x and
>   numpy master as well.
>
> The real correct would be for Cython only to issue warnings when the
>   size of dtypes/ufuncs has changes in a way that breaks the ABI, and be
>   silent otherwise.

As a result, Cython's devs [agreed to trust the numpy team with maintaining binary compatibility by hand](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.devel/14352/focus=14354), so we can probably expect that using versions with breaking ABI changes would yield a specially-crafted exception or some other explicit show-stopper.

---

¹<sub>The previously available `--no-use-wheel` option has been removed [since `pip 10.0.0`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/95b9541ed4b73632a53c2bc192144bb9e9af1c6b).</sub>

Comment: Doc links: [`--no-binary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary), [per-requirement overrides for requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides). Also, I came here for `pandas`, so here's the relevant [`pandas` GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22444#issuecomment-414830201).

Comment: I had the same error when I tried to install `top2vec` and the tools I needed to run `pip install --no-binary :all: top2vec` were to first install `llvmlite` and `numba` via `anaconda install`.

Answer (score 37):

It's the issue of new numpy version (1.15.0)

You can downgrade numpy and this problem will be fixed:

**`sudo pip uninstall numpy

 sudo pip install numpy==1.14.5`**

> Finally numpy 1.15.1 version is released so the warning issues are fixed.
>
> sudo pip install numpy==1.15.1

This is working..

Comment: By mistake the code that quiets that warning was removed between 1.14.5 and 1.15.0. The [fix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/11634) is part of the 1.15.1 bugfix release, which should be out by the end of August 2018

Comment: Thanks @mattip. `pip install numpy==1.15.1` got me from 1.15.0 to 1.15.1 and the warning messages went away.

Comment: With numpy 1.15.0, I got the above report warning msg when importing PyTables version 3.4.4 and H5Py version 2.8.0. The warning disappeared after installing Numpy version 1.15.1.

Comment: This only works if downgrading is possible, which is not always true. As NumPy progresses, this solution becomes more and more outdated.

Answer (score 9):

I've tried the above-mentioned ways, but nothing worked. But the issue was gone after I installed the libraries through apt install,

For Python3,

```
pip3 uninstall -y numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-pandas python3-sklearn
```

For Python2,

```
pip uninstall -y numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-numpy python-scipy python-pandas python-sklearn
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you uninstalled Py2 versions and installed the Py3 ones.

Comment: Seems Installing python3 versions solved my issue too.

Comment: If you install binary packages, including `numpy`, from the official distro's repository rather than from PyPI, of course they are all compiled against that same `numpy`. The downside is you may not be getting the latest versions.

Answer (score 8):

Just upgrade your numpy module, right now it is 1.15.4. For windows

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: this helped i guess

Answer (score 7):

if you are in an anaconda environment simply use:

```
conda update --all
```

or:

```
conda update numpy
```

Comment: Or update just numpy which worked for me: ```conda update numpy```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the installed packages were build agains different version of numpy.
We need to rebuild scipy and scikit-learn against the local `numpy`.

For new `pip` (in my case `pip 18.0`) this worked:

```
pip uninstall -y scipy scikit-learn
pip install --no-binary scipy,scikit-learn -I scipy scikit-learn
```

`--no-binary` takes a list of names of packages that you want to ignore binaries for. In this case we passed `--no-binary scipy,scikit-learn` which will ignore binaries for packages scipy,scikit-learn.
Didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Meta-information: [The recommended way to install sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

> If you already have a working installation of numpy and scipy, the
>   easiest way to install scikit-learn is using `pip`
>
> ```
> pip install -U scikit-learn
> ```
>
> or `conda`:
>
> ```
> conda install scikit-learn
> ```

[... do not compile from source using pip]

> If you don’t already have a python installation with numpy and scipy, we recommend to install either via your package manager or via [a](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy) [python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) [bundle](https://winpython.github.io/). These come with numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, matplotlib and many other helpful scientific and data processing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of cython 0.29 there is a new [check_size option](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2627) that eliminates the warning at the source, so no work-arounds should be needed once that version percolates to the various packages

Answer (score -4):

My enviroment is Python 2.7.15

I try

```
pip uninstall
pip install --no-use-wheel
```

but it does not work. It shows the error:

> no such option: --no-use-wheel

Then I try:

```
pip uninstall
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

And it works: the useless warnings do not show.

Comment: The option `--no-use-wheel` has been removed. Use `--no-binary :all:` instead.

Answer (score -6):

When import scipy, error info shows: RuntimeWarning: **builtin**.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected zd, got zd

I solved this problem by updating python version from 2.7.2 to 2.7.13