# Python error when importing package: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, tensorflow, pip

EDIT: A mod flagged this post as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility) thread but issue in that thread was with scipy and was solved by simply reinstalling scipy with the --no-wheel flag. I am installing tensorflow and the solutions listed in that thread are not solving the problem. Another common answer is to suppress warnings which I don't believe is a great solution.

I am getting a strange error when I import tensorflow with Python. The message says numpy.dtype size changed. Below is a copy of my console output. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
sam@sam-MS-7B46:~$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

I have all the correct dependencies installed. Here is a snippet of pipdeptree showing the installed dependencies and requirements.

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0
  - absl-py [required: >=0.1.6, installed: 0.2.2]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
  - astor [required: >=0.6.0, installed: 0.7.1]
  - gast [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.0]
  - grpcio [required: >=1.8.6, installed: 1.13.0]
    - six [required: >=1.5.2, installed: 1.11.0]
  - numpy [required: >=1.13.3, installed: 1.15.0]
  - protobuf [required: >=3.4.0, installed: 3.6.0]
    - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 39.2.0]
    - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.11.0]
  - setuptools [required: <=39.1.0, installed: 39.2.0]
  - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.11.0]
  - tensorboard [required: >=1.9.0,<1.10.0, installed: 1.9.0]
    - markdown [required: >=2.6.8, installed: 2.6.11]
    - numpy [required: >=1.12.0, installed: 1.15.0]
    - protobuf [required: >=3.4.0, installed: 3.6.0]
      - setuptools [required: Any, installed: 39.2.0]
      - six [required: >=1.9, installed: 1.11.0]
    - six [required: >=1.10.0, installed: 1.11.0]
    - werkzeug [required: >=0.11.10, installed: 0.14.1]
    - wheel [required: >=0.26, installed: 0.31.1]
  - termcolor [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.1.0]
  - wheel [required: >=0.26, installed: 0.31.1]
```

As you can see, my numpy instalation meets the reqirements. Everything works when I install in a virtualenv however I would like to run tensorflow natively and I am getting this strange error.

What is the meaning of this message and how can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: @hoefling The solutions presented in that thread are to either suppress the warnings which isn't a great solution or to reinstall the package which I have tried many times. Thanks

Comment: No, the solution is to check what packages depend on `numpy` and find out against what `numpy` version they were built. Then install that particular version so the binaries in the dependent packages are compatible to it.

Comment: Most probably it should be 1.13.3 that you have to install instead of 1.15, based on the deps you've provided.

Comment: In my virtualenv I can run tensorflow with no problems and I have numpy 1.15 installed there. The requirements show >= 1.13.3.

Comment: @hoefling You were right I installed numpy 1.13.3 with `pip3 install --user numpy=1.13.3`. My only question now is why it worked in the virutal environment when I don't seem to have that version of numpy installed. If you post that as an answer I will mark it as correct.