# Error importing pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I already installed pandas using

```
pip install pandas
```

When I import pandas using

```
import pandas
```

I get this error:

> untimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary
>   incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility)

Comment: Please try steps mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility