# Pandas Runtime Warning on import

Tags: python, pandas

I just installed the latest version of Pandas (both for Python2 and 3), and when I import it, I get this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py:4: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py:26: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py:6: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos, lib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/util/hashing.py:7: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import hashing, tslib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:7: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import (lib, index as libindex, tslib as libts,
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py:21: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets as liboffsets
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:16: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos as libalgos, ops as libops
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/interval.py:32: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs.interval import (
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:14: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import internals as libinternals
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/sparse/array.py:33: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.sparse as splib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py:36: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.window as _window
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:68: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import (lib, reduction,
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py:30: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos as _algos, reshape as _reshape
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:45: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  import pandas._libs.parsers as parsers
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py:50: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  from pandas._libs import algos, lib, writers as libwriters
```

Still, it seems as everything works fine. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility)