# My Python console keeps giving me errors when I try to import pandas

Tags: python

报错代码：ValueError: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 888 from C header, got 880 from PyObject
已经安装pandas模块和numpy库

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility) out

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pip installed?

If so, can you run the following command and show us what version of pandas you have installed? You run the command in your command prompt / terminal.
`pip list`

Also, run this and let us know the version
`python --version`

Can you try the following python script and see if it works?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Finally, are you importing pandas at the top of your python script? If so, how are you doing it? Copy and paste your code into your question to show us. That will give a good hint for those helping.