# DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cac

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was getting this error on running my python file:

```
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
```

On following this post : [RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility)

I did:

```
!pip uninstall -y scipy scikit-learn
!pip install --no-binary scipy scikit-learn
```

But, I am getting this now:

```
DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you using a notebook? Did you restart it?

Comment: Please change your title to something more descriptive, and provide a bit more background around what you're actually doing? As it stands, the question is a bit of a mess and can't be reproduced.

Comment: @mozway yes, I am using Jupyter notebook. I restarted as well.