# RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I keep getting this warning `RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88` when I try to run the following program. I searched for it and followed the following link but it didn't help. Any idea how should I fix it?

([Scipy error: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility (and associated strange behavior)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752444/scipy-error-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-and))

Thank you.
The code tries to get some real-time data from a server (Seedlink server) and write it to a text file.

My code is here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import numpy as np
import obspy
from obspy.clients.seedlink.easyseedlink import create_client
count = 0



def main():
    global count
    def handle_data(trace):
        if count > 3:
            sys.exit()

        print('Received new data:')
        print(trace)
        print()
        trace.write("data.mseed")
        st = obspy.read("data.mseed")
        for i, tr in enumerate(st):
            f = open("%s_%d" % ("out_file.txt", i), "a")
            np.savetxt(f, tr.data, fmt="%f")
            f.close()
        count = count + 1
    client = create_client('rtserve.iris.washington.edu:18000', handle_data)
    client.select_stream('IU', 'ANMO', 'BHZ')
    client.run()
```

Comment: Same warning when importing `pandas` (after upgrade of numpy to 1.15): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815132/recieving-an-aggrivating-runtimewarning-error-using-numpy

Comment: I know the problem is coming from the `import obspy` line but don't know how to fix it!

Comment: From the comments of another recent spat of such warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility.  Seems to come from a package that has been compiled against an earlier numpy version.

Comment: @hpaulj I referred to the link you mentioned and I've tried it already but it didn't help.

Comment: Other than the warning does the code still work?

Comment: @hpaulj No, it doesn't. The warning only shows up in the console.

Comment: A closed `numpy` issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11628

Comment: Probably the following link would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility

Comment: @hpaulj,Thanks!

Comment: @Sid,   Thank you!