# Warning when importing Scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

The simple code

```py
import sklearn
```

gives me the warning

```
:219: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
```

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe [Scipy error: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility (and associated strange behavior)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752444/scipy-error-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-and) and its accepted answer helps.

Comment: what is your numpy version?

Answer (score 0):

I replicate this situation on my colab and it works fine. Error generate in your case because of library version issue.

As per the latest release scikit-learn requires:

```
Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3)
Numpy (>= 1.6.1)
SciPy (>= 0.9)
```

So possible solutions can be:

Check the version of Python, NumPy, and SciPy and if the version is below the requirement then install the latest one.